# How do I fix GL.h Compiling Errors in QT?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl, compiler-errors

I have been having a problem with building my application with my custom `glwidget` for OpenGL in QT. `GL.h` throws 492 errors starting on line 1157 with the statement of

> syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';' " (using windows).

**glwidget.h**

```cpp
    #ifndef GLWIDGET_H
    #define GLWIDGET_H

    #include <QOpenGLFunctions>
    #include <QGLWidget>

    class GLWidget : public QGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit GLWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);

        void initializeGL();
        void paintGL();
        void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    };

    #endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

**glwidget.cpp**

```cpp
    #include "glwidget.h"

    #include <gl/GL.h>
    #include <gl/GLU.h>

    GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget* parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
    {

    }

    void GLWidget::initializeGL()
    {
        glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    }

    void GLWidget::paintGL()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
    {

    }
```

What would be the solution to my problem? Also I am using the latest Windows Development Kit, and I am using QT 5.14.0 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit) on c++11.

All the errors start at line 1157 and goes throughout the rest of the code afterwards; I have pasted the section of [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/fmCZNzWn) with all the errors, it all is on the lines of WINGDIAPI and typedef, than I excluded the last couple lines which are just ifdef and endif stuff which don't have the errors.

Comment: Please show the complete error message verbatim and show/tag the line of code that is causing the problem.  Also note that [`QGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html) is obsolete -- you should use [`QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) instead.

Comment: That was the whole first error message (only part it didn't include was the directory of GL.h for the newest Windows Development Kit), and thanks for the heads up on [QGLWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html) being obsolete.

Comment: Even after I recoded my glwidget to use QOpenGLWidget, the GL.h code errors still showed up in console when running the build process.

Comment: I have also added all the code which causes the error from the GL.h

Comment: Please show the relevant code as text in your question *not* via a link (note also that the code in the link appears to be incomplete).

Comment: Well it should be fixed, the errors occur in about 450 lines, also adding #include <Windows.h> brings down the error count to 369, what files are needed to include to get GL.h to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

right before every occurrence of `#include <GL/gl.h>`.

Also take not of the case of the directory/file names. It's a capital `GL/` and a lowercase `gl.h`. It doesn't matter on Windows, but if you compile on Linux and FreeBSD that's the proper way.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much, now it fires my initialize and paint event, idk about resize because an error is thrown from QOpenGLFunctions but that's another problem, I would +1 but it won't display because I don't have enough Reputation.